# How to send array from javascript to JSp

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp

In my code I need to send an array from javascript to Jsp I did many times and I'm unable to get the output I'm getting array will printing that array Please help me where i'm missing

My code is

```
   <%@page import="sun.security.util.Length"%>
   <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   <script>
   function funct()
   {
   var h=localStorage.getItem('m');
   location.replace("test1jsp.jsp?arr="+h);
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body onLoad="funct();">
   <%
   String arr[]=request.getParameterValues("arr");
   List<String> larr = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("arr");
   for(int p = 0; p < 3; p++)
   out.println((String)larr.get(p));
   out.println(arr);
   %>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your query string correctly. You can't just slap an array onto a string and expect it to be properly encoded.

You repeat the key for each value in the array.

```
var h=localStorage.getItem('m');
var query_string = "";
h.forEach(function (value) {
   if (query_string.length) {
       query_string = query_string + "&";
   }
   query_string = query_string + "arr=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
}

location.replace("test1jsp.jsp?" + query_string);
```

Comment: i tried using converting array to sting in javascript and returned to jsp but i'm unable to retrieve array from string